# Display and hide div contain after select

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript function that allows me to hide and display after clicking on a button. each button has a div linked to it. when i click on a button the previous button contain is hidden and the second button displays his contains. i woulk like to use a select instead to do the same job. i'm stuck there. Please help me to reach my goal i post the way i did it with button. Bear with me.

```
function visibilite(id) {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(var no=0;no<divs.length;no++){
        if(divs[ no].className=='divs')
        { 
            'divs'
            divs[ no].style.display = "none"; 
        }
}
document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block"; 


<a href="javascript:visibilite('test1');" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> 
 1 year
</a>
 <a href="javascript:visibilite('test2');"class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">  
 2 year 
</a>
<div id="test1" class="divs" style="display:yes">
sfssdfsdfsfsf
</div>

<div id="test2" class="divs" style="display:none">
sfssdfsdfsfsf
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have the string `'divs'` on a line by itself in the `if` block (it's not a syntax error, but it looks odd, unless it's there for a reason that you haven't shown)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/22/)**.

You can use `onchange` in select tag, check the following example.

**NOTE :** in `display:yes` yes is not a valide value for `display` attribute.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
function visibilite(_this)
{
    var id = _this.value;
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

    for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
        if(divs[i].className=='divs')
        {
          divs[i].style.display = "none"; 
        }
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block"; 
}
```

```html
<select onchange='visibilite(this)'>
    <option value='test1'>1 year</option>
    <option value='test2'>2 year</option>
</select>

<div id="test1" class="divs">First year content</div>
<br>
<div id="test2" class="divs" style="display:none">Second year content</div>
```

Comment: it works as i wanted it thank so much. I don't know why when click on the arrow to vote the number doesn't appear it still remains 0

Comment: Please take this as constructive, but you should adopt a defensive coding approach, check the return from each function, never assume that the call to a function will succeed...if it can go wrong then you should check and allow for it, this way your code will work as expected.

Comment: i'm facing a new problem with the codes structure because the div test1 and test2 contain fields of a form. test2 has the fields of test1 plus other fields. it's difficult to save the form when i display test2 fields cause some fields have the same names...More over all the fields in test1 and test2 are required when i display test2 and i fill all the fields i can't save because the fields in test1 are required as well...

Comment: Try to post another question with clear description since i can't give you perfect answer without more much info.